# JavaScript: Collision detection

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

How does collision detection work in JavaScript?

I can't use jQuery or gameQuery - already using prototype - so, I'm looking for something very simple. I am not asking for complete solution, just point me to the right direction.

Let's say there's:

```
<div id="ball"></div>
and
<div id="someobject0"></div>
```

Now the ball is moving (any direction). "Someobject"(0-X) is already pre-defined and there's 20-60 of them randomly positioned like this:

```
#someobject {position: absolute; top: RNDpx; left: RNDpx;}
```

I can create an array with "someobject(X)" positions and test collision while the "ball" is moving... Something like:

```
for(var c=0; c<objposArray.length; c++){
........ and code to check ball's current position vs all objects one by one....
}
```

But I guess this would be a "noob" solution and it looks pretty slow.
Is there anything better?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first thing to have is the actual function that will detect whether you have a collision between the ball and the object.

For the sake of performance it will be great to implement some crude collision detecting technique, e.g., [bounding rectangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle), and a more accurate one if needed in case you have collision detected, so that your function will run a little bit quicker but using exactly the same loop.

Another option that can help to increase performance is to do some pre-processing with the objects you have. For example you can break the whole area into cells like a generic table and store the appropriate object that are contained within the particular cells. Therefore to detect the collision you are detecting the cells occupied by the ball, get the objects from those cells and use your collision-detecting function.

To speed it up even more you can implement [2d-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree), [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Answer (score 85):

Here's a very simple bounding rectangle routine. It expects both `a` and `b` to be objects with `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties:

```
function isCollide(a, b) {
    return !(
        ((a.y + a.height) < (b.y)) ||
        (a.y > (b.y + b.height)) ||
        ((a.x + a.width) < b.x) ||
        (a.x > (b.x + b.width))
    );
}
```

To see this function in action, [here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/mixal_bl4/pen/qZYWOm) graciously made by [@MixerOID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051938/mixeroid).

Comment: Can anyone clarify what I am doing wrong with this? It always returns true regardless of 'collision' http://jsbin.com/akeSeDI/2/edit

Comment: @KryptoniteDove: unfortunately you can't simply input a DOM element in this routine, you need some kind of conversion (e.g. using jQuery). Also, your divs should probably use `position: absolute` instead of `relative`. Here's a fork of your version that works: http://jsbin.com/akeSeDI/3/edit

Comment: I created visual GUI to this wonderful function :) http://codepen.io/mixal_bl4/pen/qZYWOm You can add this to you answer :)

Comment: this requires jQuerz and hence  would not be a valid answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35974082/3580261 is actually correct and leans on this function.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe my code doesn't require jQuery. It just requires objects with the given properties, which you could get with jQuery, but also with the methods described in your function.

Comment: @Husky sorry, but those a are an awful lot of pre-assumptions for the question asking for a JS solution and then being something that looks *very* much like jQuery. It's just confusing and since you don't check for the property existence but still return a (discrete) boolean, I would still regard it as incorrect.

Answer (score 40):

An answer without jQuery, with HTML elements as parameters:

This is a better approach that checks the real position of the elements as they are being shown on the viewport, even if they're absolute, relative or have been manipulated via transformations:

```
function isCollide(a, b) {
    var aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    var bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();

    return !(
        ((aRect.top + aRect.height) < (bRect.top)) ||
        (aRect.top > (bRect.top + bRect.height)) ||
        ((aRect.left + aRect.width) < bRect.left) ||
        (aRect.left > (bRect.left + bRect.width))
    );
}
```

Comment: In fact it should be the only answer to the above question. The top answer requires jQuery

Answer (score 23):

You can try [jquery-collision](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/). Full disclosure: I just wrote this and released it. I didn't find a solution, so I wrote it myself.

It allows you to do:

```
var hit_list = $("#ball").collision("#someobject0");
```

which will return all the "#someobject0"'s that overlap with "#ball".

Comment: The OP says they can't use jQuery. Still nice though, helped me in my own solution.

Comment: @irwin - hmm, i was going on the "can't use jquery -- using prototype" as in, i'm pretty sure you can actually mix them. i haven't tried, though, honestly. glad it helped you though! try jquery-draggable-collision, too! :-)

Comment: @PeterAjtai: no, it's on sourceforge, why?

Comment: @eruciform - Just curious. I've used github a lot, but not sourceforge. I'd fork this on github, but I'm not familiar enough with sourceforge to know if I can do something similar or only download the source (i.e. I'd like to stay in synch with future updates).

Comment: @eruciform sourceforge is almost unusable.  I'm sure a lot of people would like it if it were on github

Comment: @PeterAjtai - I'll probably be moving them all over this summer to github. It's just been zero updates for a while, so no motivation to break what worked. However, I'll be adding things soon!

Comment: @Scoop - I'll probably be moving them all over this summer to github. It's just been zero updates for a while, so no motivation to break what worked. However, I'll be adding things soon!

Comment: @eruciform Which summer? :D

Comment: Not *"[jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)-collision"*?

Answer (score 13):

Mozilla has a good article on this, with the code shown below.

*[2D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)*

Rectangle collision

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
    // Collision detected!
}
```

Circle collision

```
if (distance < circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
    // Collision detected!
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[bcm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection/5480590#5480590), which has 0 votes at this time, is actually a great, under-appreciated answer. It uses good old [Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to detect when objects are closer than their combined bounding circles. Simple collision detection often uses rectangular collision detection, which is fine if your sprites tend to be, well, rectangular. If they are circular (or otherwise less than rectangular), such as a ball, an asteroid, or any other shape where the extreme corners are usually transparent, you may find this efficient routine to be the most accurate.

But for clarity, here is a more fully realized version of the code:

```
function doCollide(x1, y1, w1, x2, y2, w2) {
    var xd = x1 - x2;
    var yd = y1 - y2;
    var wt = w2 + w1;
    return (xd * xd + yd * yd <= wt * wt);
}
```

Where the parameters to pass in are the x,y and width values of two different sprite objects.

Answer (score 8):

This is a lightweight solution I've come across -

```
function E() { // Check collision
    S = X - x;
    D = Y - y;
    F = w + W;
    return (S * S + D * D <= F * F)
}
```

The big and small variables are of two objects, (x coordinate, y coordinate, and w width)

From [here](http://js1k.com/2011-dysentery/demo/917).

Comment: As far as I can see, this function assumes that the objects are square (or even circular?). Also it appears less readable that Husky's code above, and if that wasn't enough, it also seems to be slower (see: http://jsperf.com/simple-collision-detection)

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way that is inefficient, but it's quite reasonable when you don't need anything too complex or you don't have many objects.

Otherwise there are many different algorithms, but most of them are quite complex to implement.

For example, you can use a *[divide et impera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule)* approach in which you cluster objects hierarchically according to their distance and you give to every cluster a bounding box that contains all the items of the cluster. Then you can check which clusters collide and avoid checking pairs of object that belong to clusters that are not colliding/overlapped.

Otherwise, you can figure out a generic space partitioning algorithm to split up in a similar way the objects to avoid useless checks. These kind of algorithms split the collision detection in two phases: a *coarse* one in which you see what objects maybe colliding and a *fine* one in which you effectively check single objects.
For example, you can use a [**QuadTree**](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (Wikipedia) to work out an easy solution...

Take a look at [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection). It can give you some hints.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Off the cuff, Prototype style. 
//Note, this is not optimal; there should be some basic partitioning and caching going on. 
(function () { 
    var elements = []; 
    Element.register = function (element) { 
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) { 
            if (elements[i]==element) break; 
        } 
        elements.push(element); 
        if (arguments.length>1)  
            for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)  
                Element.register(arguments[i]); 
    }; 
    Element.collide = function () { 
        for (var outer=0; outer < elements.length; outer++) { 
            var e1 = Object.extend( 
                $(elements[outer]).positionedOffset(), 
                $(elements[outer]).getDimensions() 
            ); 
            for (var inner=outer; inner<elements.length; innter++) { 
                var e2 = Object.extend( 
                    $(elements[inner]).positionedOffset(), 
                    $(elements[inner]).getDimensions() 
                ); 
                if (     
                    (e1.left+e1.width)>=e2.left && e1.left<=(e2.left+e2.width) && 
                    (e1.top+e1.height)>=e2.top && e1.top<=(e2.top+e2.height) 
                ) { 
                    $(elements[inner]).fire(':collision', {element: $(elements[outer])}); 
                    $(elements[outer]).fire(':collision', {element: $(elements[inner])}); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }; 
})(); 

//Usage: 
Element.register(myElementA); 
Element.register(myElementB); 
$(myElementA).observe(':collision', function (ev) { 
    console.log('Damn, '+ev.memo.element+', that hurt!'); 
}); 
//detect collisions every 100ms 
setInterval(Element.collide, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

**hittest.js;** detect two transparent PNG images (pixel) colliding.

[Demo and download link](http://bug7a.github.io/hittest.js/)

#### HTML code

```
<img id="png-object-1" src="images/object1.png" />
<img id="png-object-2" src="images/object2.png" />
```

#### Init function

```
var pngObject1Element = document.getElementById( "png-object-1" );
var pngObject2Element = document.getElementById( "png-object-2" );

var object1HitTest = new HitTest( pngObject1Element );
```

#### Basic usage

```
if( object1HitTest.toObject( pngObject2Element ) ) {
    // Collision detected
}
```