# How to find the image intersection in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins, canvas, html5-canvas

Can anyone please tell me how I can detect whether two images intersect or not?
Actually, I had two images, one image can rotate. I need to check that whether the second image intersects with the first image or not. Is there any function in JavaScript to check such intersection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the demo in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection/4230951#4230951

Comment: Do you need this to be **exact** (testing for single pixel overlaps in non-square semi-transparent images, and/or **fast** (able to run on many pairs of images at 30fps)?

Comment: Hi Sime sir, i checked what you have mentioned, but it is not working in my case. If i rotate the image (i.e a rectangle) and then try to find the collision (i.e rectangle (rotated) with other rectangle(movable)) it fails. please give me suggestion.