# jquery delete divs that on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm building a web browser game.
Using Jquery 1.4 as framework
But i need to delete the trees that are in the building area.
This is what happens now:
[image: What happens now]
I would like to delete the trees if they are in the image area.
Made some sample code for show: http://jsfiddle.net/coolking/evU9D/3/
I hope i've given enough info.

```
Image height: 73px image width: 107px
```

---

The code incorporating the accepted answer is here: http://jsfiddle.net/coolking/evU9D/22/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick aside: it's better practice to apply all of your event listeners in JavaScript via element.AddEventListener() than to add HTML attributes like onload="..." or onmousedown="...".

jQuery has collision detection APIs to determine exactly what you're asking. Here's a good reference: [jQuery/JavaScript collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection)

When you detect a collision, use something along the lines of $(this).remove() to remove the tree from the DOM.

I love strategy games, so I hope your game turns out well! =D

Comment: I will give you a screenshot ;) xD http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8015538/example/screenie.png
But the problem is i cant get it working! :/
The onmousedown event was fast ;) in my real code it isnt ;)

Comment: then I'm not sure what you're having trouble with. be specific and ill do my best to help.

Comment: The collision if i do like tree1 <= obj ? obj ? tree1 it would take alot of time to do that again for my over 100's of trees
you can see a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/coolking/evU9D/3/

Comment: @Jeffrey, how many trees do you have here? There are only five in your fiddle, but your comment suggests you might be working with several hundreds. Did you try Eric's suggestion?

Comment: I'm heading off to the gym and will take a look when i get back.

Comment: Looks like you're on your way