# Stop jquery droppable from accepting when droptarget is completely obscured by another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-droppable

In my user interface, I have many popup dialogs, some of which contain jquery droppable targets. They work fine, but when one popup is completely covering a drop target, I would like to stop the event from propagating.

I tried to put an event handler on the popup dialog to stop the drop event from propagating, but that didnt work.

Using the scope and accept options don't really seem to be viable, since the objects and targets are more or less identical.

Any ideas?

Comment: please give us some code

Comment: I'll see what I can do to distill this down to a minimal case. It is basically just some image tags with a droppable, other image tags with a draggable, and divs that have a high z-index and obscure the droppables. I'll post some actual code when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably to use the `disable` method on the occluded dropables when you open a dialog.  Then call the `enable` method in the dialog close event.  It might also make sense to just disable all droppables not in the most recently opened dialog.

Setting the `greedy` option to true unfortunately only stops the propagation for nested dropables so that also isn't an option for you.

Comment: I actually already considered this. The problem with this is that it needs to work if they are not occluded by a dialog, whether dialogs are open or not. The stumbling block for me then is to detect when they are covered and disable/re-enable them accordingly. Seems clunky at best.

Comment: @Tim check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection

Comment: Thanks, you answered my implicit question, I think. Collision detection is something I know how to do, it just seemed like doing it continuously in a setinterval was suboptimal.

Comment: @Tim well, you don't have to do it continuously, only when a dialog opens or moves.  So just do the checks during the dialog `open` and `dragStop` events.