# Fire an event every time part of a div overlap part of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, html, eventtrigger

I've two (but maybe more) `DIV`s, animated through `jQuery`; so now they are running all over my screen, following pseudo random paths.

I want to fire an event every time part of a `DIV`overlaps part of another one. Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to keep track of each divs position and constantly compare them to each other to see if there's overlap.

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/ and check for collisions after each animation step.