# Get all elements below a specific element

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript, is it possible to obtain a list of all elements that an element is hovering over? I'm using an element as a cursor, and I want the other elements in the page to be underlined when the cursor element is hovering over each of the other elements.

```
<div id="cursor">|----------|<br/>|----------|<br/>>I'm a spaceship!><br/>|----------|<br/>|----------|<br/></div>
<div id="hi">Try to select this text</div>
<p>I want to automatically highlight all elements that the cursor element hovers over.</p>
<p>Here's an element.<p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fU3Qn/

Comment: I just found a similar question, but I'm not sure if it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection

Answer (score 1):

The `:hover` pseudo-class applies to whatever you're cursor is over. Have a quick look at this fiddle where your mouse triggers a red background for each element hovered: http://goo.gl/zurP6

Secondly, if you are using an element as your cursor, you can instruct your mouse to pass through it by using the `pointer-events: none` rule. Note, [support outside of SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) for this property is limited.

Other than this, the only alternative way is to use something like [`elementFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but this will return only a single element. I'm not sure this would even work for you since you're mouse is always obstructed by an element to begin with.

Regarding the `elementFromPoint` route, you could temporarily hide your custom cursor to get the next element below the mouse, and then turn your custom cursor back on, as suggested in the comments below.

Comment: For `elementFromPoint`, you might be able to set `display` to `none` before calling it and restoring its previous value after.