# Jquery Drag and Drop without plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to create a drag and drop plugin using JQuery.

```
$('.draggable').on{
  mousemove : function(){
    var mouseposition = { // this also needs to account for onclick offset of pointer vis-a-vis element
        x : pageX,
        y : pageY 
    };
    $(this).css({
      top : mouseposition.y,
      left : mouseposition.y
    });
  if( // this statement is kinda bogus, idea is to perform a collision detection via coordinate comparison
    $('.draggable').offset().top < $(.droppable').offset().top 
    &&
    $('.draggable').offset().left < $(.droppable').offset().left
  ) {
      alert('the item has been dropped');
  }
  }
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XTMK8/1/) link what I have tried.

Comment: *"[...] whether what I am doing is correct or not."*: If it's not working properly then what you are doing is probably not correct. What exactly is it that "does not work fine"?

Comment: Start by getting your quotes right.

Comment: Sorry, is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reworked your code, and updated the fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/XTMK8/2/

```
var dragging = undefined;

$('.draggable').on('mousedown', function(){
    dragging = $(this);
});

$('body').on('mousemove', function(e){
    if(typeof dragging != "undefined") {
        dragging.css({
             top : e.pageY - 50,
             left : e.pageX - 50
        });       
    }
});

$('body').on('mouseup', function(){
    dragging = undefined;
});
```

**Collision Detection**

I would then recommend using the following snippet to handle collision:

[jQuery/JavaScript collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this must be an academic task or you want to do it for learning purposes (otherwise, why someone wouldn't want to use JQuery UI's draggable?) but anyway, the link below should guide in the right direction: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/

If you still want to know what's wrong with your code, I recommend starting over and add bit by bit to try to achieve the basic functionalities before coming up with a draggable and droppable at once, e.g., your mousemove function seems different from the one in JQuery's doc, I believe that, in order to retrieve pageX and pageY, you need the event object within the function's parameters:

```
$("#target").mousemove(function(event) {
  var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
  msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  $("#log").append("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
});
```

Try to set some breakpoints using Firebug and see if all variables are being populated accordingly.

I hope that helps, cheers!