# Jquery moving an img without jquery UI plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have trying for a while to move an img inside a div. but it doesnt work. 
I tried using 3 events: mouse down, mouse up and mouse move.
when the mouse down is triggered on the image it makes a boolean element to true. then if the mouse is moving across the body it takes the current state of the mouse and implements it on the img current css. it seems very logic to me.

The code is:

```js
var md = false;
$('body').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
  // Your Code to handle Mouse Move Globally.
  if (md == true) {
    var X = e.pageX - $('#pointer').offsetLeft;
    var Y = e.pageY - $('#pointer').offsetTop;
    $('#pointer').css('top', Y + 'px');
    $('#pointer').css('left', X + 'px');
  }
});


$("#pointer").mousedown(function() {
  md = true;


});

$("body").mouseup(function() {
  //if (md==true) {
  //alert('aa');}
  md = false;
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Internal variables</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Variables</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Choose an element</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="Ju-span">
         Ju= 
        </span>
      <input id="Ju-rectangle"> </input><br><br>
      <span>
         Iu= 
        </span>
      <input id="Iu-rectangle"> </input><br><br>
      <span>
         A= 
        </span>
      <input id="A-rectangle"> </input><br><br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
         b= 
        </span>
      <input id="b-rectangle"> </input><br><br>
      <span>
         d= 
        </span>
      <input id="d-rectangle"> </input><br><br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="rectangle.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="Ju-span">
         Ju= 
        </span>
      <input id="Ju-Circle"> </input><br><br>
      <span>
         Iu= 
        </span>
      <input id="Iu-Circle"> </input><br><br>
      <span>
         A= 
        </span>
      <input id="A-Circle"> </input><br><br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
         r= 
        </span>
      <input id="r-Circle"> </input><br><br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div><img src="Circle.png" id="pointer"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<div><img id="img-Axis" src="Axis.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like drag and drop ? check this answer here : 
[Jquery Drag and Drop without plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462822/jquery-drag-and-drop-without-plugins)