# Collision detection between Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, game-engine, game-physics, gamequery

I am running into some troubles with my simple Brick Breaker game. I made a simple animation for my ball object but I have a hard time with it detecting when it comes into contact with other elements on the page. Not to mention, I can't seem to keep my player tile from moving outside the container div I made for it. I simply want the ball to bounce off the player paddle, wall and bricks.

```
$(function(){
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var Playerposition = $("#player").position();
    var Ballposition = $("#ball").position();
    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 37: //Left Movement
            $("#player").css('left', Playerposition.left - 20 + 'px');
        break;
        case 39://Right movement   
            $("#player").css('left', Playerposition.left + 20 + 'px');
        break;   
    }
});
var top = 275;
var left = 325;
var interval = 5; // time interval in milliseconds
var increment = 1;
var move = function() {
     if(left > 750) {
        increment = -increment;
     }
     if(left < 0) {
        increment = -increment
     }
    if(top > 325){
    increment = -increment; 
    }
    if(top < 0) {
    increment = -increment;
     }
    top = top + increment;
     left = left + increment;
     $('#ball').css('left', left + 'px');
    $('#ball').css('top', top + 'px');
};
setInterval(move, interval)});
```

I do have gameQuery installed, as well as Jquery. This is my game so far with my current html/css/javascript: [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK3dV/) Sorry it does match up well, it looks fine with a full webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it:

[jQuery/JavaScript collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection)

Check the `detectOverlapping` method souce.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want collision detection to work with gameQuery you have to use the provided `.x()`,`.y()` or `.xy()` function and not directly change the sprite position with `.css()`

This is true for all of the elements of the game, that includes groups and tilemaps too.