# Detect overlapping of two dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, php, html

My images move around the page in different directions.
When two images collide I want to throw an alert.

Images are loaded like this:

```
    <?php foreach($logos as $logo) { $id = $logo['Id']; $logoName = $logo['Logo_Link']; ?>
        <img  class="imglogo" src="images/<?php echo $logoName ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Is there anyway with JavaScript I could detect when any of the elements overlap?

Comment: Is it intended behavior to make the images "move around the page in different directions"?

Comment: Even better if you add a screenshot showing non colliding images and colliding images.

Comment: Yes, it is. When two images touch I need to log an alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection)

Comment: You can try to use [intersection observe API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) or there is a polyfill for browsers that don't supports it