# Highlight animation on spinning wheel

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a this spinning wheel, what I am trying to do is when the wheel starts spinning the block which is currently in the center should have opacity 100% and the rest is lets say 50% so it will give that highlight effect.

[Codepen link:](https://codepen.io/hugoptz_/pen/qBEpOve)

`Code in link`

Thanks in advance

Block in the center should be highlighted when spinning

Comment: If we do this in javascript it's gonna affect performance heavily since you're gonna check the position of every block relative to the line in the middle every second. if you want an alternative to this, you could probably have 2 semi-transparent elements or pseudo-elements on both sides of your selector and have a gap the size of 1 block between them. not the effect you want, but close

Comment: could You show me example in code how would it look like ?

Comment: do you want to show the element under the selector like in the focus?

Comment: I don’t see any css or js in your code pen that attempts to set opacity.

Comment: yes because I didnt know how to do it thats why I asked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have all the `.card` elements have `opacity: 0.5`. We shall apply the `opacity: 1` on the active `.card` as needed. To try to keep it as performant as possible, we only listen for active positional change when the spinner is spinning. We use `requestAnimationFrame()` to time our checks to the display frame.

```js
const {
  start,
  stop,
  tick
} = (() => {
  // Whether we should be actively listening for changes in the active item.
  let highlightListen = false;
  // The currently highlighted item.
  let active;

  // Do a check of which element should be highlighted.
  const tick = () => {
    // Get the x-coordinate of the middle of the screen.
    const middle = window.innerWidth / 2;
    const middleCard = document
      // Get all elements at the point in the document of x: middle, y: 50px.
      .elementsFromPoint(middle, 50)
      // Filter this list to `.card` elements.
      .filter((element) => element.matches('.card'))
      // Get the first item from this array.
      ?.[0];

    // If this middle card is different from the last-known active item.
    if (active !== middleCard) {
      // Remove the highlight opacity style that was on the previously
      // active item.
      if (active) {
        active.style.opacity = '';
      }
      // Add the highlight opacity style to the new middle card. Check
      // that it exists since we might have hit an instance where the
      // the middle of the screen is not on a card.
      if (middleCard) {
        middleCard.style.opacity = '1';
      }
      // Store the new middle card.
      active = middleCard;
    }

    // If we should be listening to positional changes, run this check
    // again on the next drawing frame.
    if (highlightListen) {
      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
  };

  return {
    // Start listening for active changes.
    start() {
      highlightListen = true;
      tick();
    },
    // Stop listening for active changes.
    stop() {
      highlightListen = false;
    },
    // Do a single check.
    tick,
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  //setup multiple rows of colours, can also add and remove while spinning but overall this is easier.
  initWheel();
  // Once all the elements are set up, do a single check to mark the initial state.
  tick();

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var outcome = parseInt($('input').val());
    spinWheel(outcome);
  });
});

function initWheel() {
  var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
    row = "";

  row += "<div class='row'>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>1<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>14<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>2<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>13<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>3<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>12<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>4<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card green'>0<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>11<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>5<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>10<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>6<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>9<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>7<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>8<\/div>";
  row += "<\/div>";

  for (var x = 0; x < 29; x++) {
    $wheel.append(row);
  }
}

function spinWheel(roll) {
  var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
    order = [0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4],
    position = order.indexOf(roll);

  //determine position where to land
  var rows = 12,
    card = 75 + 3 * 2,
    landingPosition = (rows * 15 * card) + (position * card);

  var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) - (75 / 2);

  landingPosition = landingPosition + randomize;

  var object = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) / 100,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) / 100
  };

  $wheel.css({
    'transition-timing-function': 'cubic-bezier(0,' + object.x + ',' + object.y + ',1)',
    'transition-duration': '6s',
    'transform': 'translate3d(-' + landingPosition + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
  });

  // Start active positional checking.
  start();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $wheel.css({
      'transition-timing-function': '',
      'transition-duration': '',
    });

    var resetTo = -(position * card + randomize);
    $wheel.css('transform', 'translate3d(' + resetTo + 'px, 0px, 0px)');

    // Stop active positional checking.
    stop();
  }, 6 * 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  background: #191B28;
}

.roulette-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.roulette-wrapper .selector {
  width: 3px;
  background: grey;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.roulette-wrapper .wheel {
  display: flex;
}

.roulette-wrapper .wheel .row {
  display: flex;
}

.roulette-wrapper .wheel .row .card {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.card.red {
  background: #F95146;
}

.card.black {
  background: #2D3035;
}

.card.green {
  background: #00C74D;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='roulette-wrapper'>
  <div class='selector'></div>
  <div class='wheel'></div>
</div>

<div>
  <input placeholder='outcome'>
  <button>
    Spin Wheel
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: that seems to be exactly thisss

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //setup multiple rows of colours, can also add and remove while spinning but overall this is easier.
  initWheel();

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var outcome = parseInt($('input').val());
    spinWheel(outcome);
  });
});

function initWheel() {
  var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
    row = "";

  row += "<div class='row'>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>1<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>14<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>2<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>13<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>3<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>12<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>4<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card green'>0<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>11<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>5<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>10<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>6<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>9<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>7<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>8<\/div>";
  row += "<\/div>";

  for (var x = 0; x < 29; x++) {
    $wheel.append(row);
  }
}

function spinWheel(roll) {
  var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
    order = [0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4],
    position = order.indexOf(roll);

  //determine position where to land
  var rows = 12,
    card = 75 + 3 * 2,
    landingPosition = (rows * 15 * card) + (position * card);

  var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) - (75 / 2);

  landingPosition = landingPosition + randomize;

  var object = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) / 100,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) / 100
  };

  $wheel.css({
    'transition-timing-function': 'cubic-bezier(0,' + object.x + ',' + object.y + ',1)',
    'transition-duration': '6s',
    'transform': 'translate3d(-' + landingPosition + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $wheel.css({
      'transition-timing-function': '',
      'transition-duration': '',
    });

    var resetTo = -(position * card + randomize);
    $wheel.css('transform', 'translate3d(' + resetTo + 'px, 0px, 0px)');
  }, 6 * 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  background: #191B28;
}

.roulette-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.roulette-wrapper .selector {
  width: 3px;
  background: grey;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* What I added */
.roulette-wrapper .selector:before,
.roulette-wrapper .selector:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50vw - (75px / 2));
  background: #191B28;
  opacity: 50%
}

.roulette-wrapper .selector:before {
  right: 37px;
}

.roulette-wrapper .selector:after {
  left: 37px;
}
/****************/

.roulette-wrapper .wheel {
  display: flex;
}

.roulette-wrapper .wheel .row {
  display: flex;
}

.roulette-wrapper .wheel .row .card {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.card.red {
  background: #F95146;
}

.card.black {
  background: #2D3035;
}

.card.green {
  background: #00C74D;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='roulette-wrapper'>
  <div class='selector'></div>
  <div class='wheel'></div>
</div>

<div>
  <input placeholder='outcome'>
  <button>
    Spin Wheel
  </button>
</div>
```

It's not exactly what you wanted but it's close and less heavy on the computing side

Answer (score 0):

How to check overlapping you can find here
[jQuery/JavaScript collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection)
But I'm not sure that your solution is correct...

Comment: in your code, it could be something like this one
in `initWheel` fix row initialization
   `row += "<div class='row'>";
    row += "  <div class='list card red'>1<\/div>";...`
in `spinWheel` method add this one:

`var list = $('.list');`
in the `setTimeout` method add this one:
`[...list].find((element) => {
        if (isOverlapping($selector,element)) {
          element.style = 'opacity: 100%';
        } else {
          element.style = 'opacity: 50%';
        }

      });`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to overlay the cards with a semi transparent grayish color, with the middle bit transparent. That way no extra calculations have to happen.

Here's a simple snippet - overlaying with a black, transparent, black linear-gradient. Obviously you can alter that to get the effect you want.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    background: #191B28;
  }
  
  .roulette-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .roulette-wrapper::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent calc(50% - (75px / 2)) calc(50% + (75px / 2)), black);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .roulette-wrapper .selector {
    width: 3px;
    background: grey;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .roulette-wrapper .wheel {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .roulette-wrapper .wheel .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .roulette-wrapper .wheel .row .card {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
  .card.red {
    background: #F95146;
  }
  
  .card.black {
    background: #2D3035;
  }
  
  .card.green {
    background: #00C74D;
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>
<div class='roulette-wrapper'>
  <div class='selector'></div>
  <div class='wheel'></div>
</div>

<div>
  <input placeholder='outcome'>
  <button>
    Spin Wheel
  </button>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //setup multiple rows of colours, can also add and remove while spinning but overall this is easier.
    initWheel();

    $('button').on('click', function() {
      var outcome = parseInt($('input').val());
      spinWheel(outcome);
    });
  });

  function initWheel() {
    var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
      row = "";

    row += "<div class='row'>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>1<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>14<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>2<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>13<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>3<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>12<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>4<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card green'>0<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>11<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>5<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>10<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>6<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>9<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card red'>7<\/div>";
    row += "  <div class='card black'>8<\/div>";
    row += "<\/div>";

    for (var x = 0; x < 29; x++) {
      $wheel.append(row);
    }
  }

  function spinWheel(roll) {
    var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
      order = [0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4],
      position = order.indexOf(roll);

    //determine position where to land
    var rows = 12,
      card = 75 + 3 * 2,
      landingPosition = (rows * 15 * card) + (position * card);

    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) - (75 / 2);

    landingPosition = landingPosition + randomize;

    var object = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) / 100,
      y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) / 100
    };

    $wheel.css({
      'transition-timing-function': 'cubic-bezier(0,' + object.x + ',' + object.y + ',1)',
      'transition-duration': '6s',
      'transform': 'translate3d(-' + landingPosition + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      $wheel.css({
        'transition-timing-function': '',
        'transition-duration': '',
      });

      var resetTo = -(position * card + randomize);
      $wheel.css('transform', 'translate3d(' + resetTo + 'px, 0px, 0px)');
    }, 6 * 1000);
  }
</script>
```

Note: the GPU usage on my laptop was 15% when this was running.