# PNG Collision sensing in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on a platformer game in HTML5 canvas with javascript. I need a way to sense collisions between two weird shaped png images drawn onto the canvas. I could do it with squares or circles but these are strange shaped images. Does anyone have any idea of how to do this? Sense collisions between two strange shaped objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection)

Answer (score 3):

Box2d is popular:

http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/

I think doing pixel-per-pixel checking, as in old time sprite games, might be little too CPU consuming on JS - not sure though.

cocos2d-javascript has some demos related to this:

http://cocos2d-javascript.org/demo

Comment: Those collision detection systems are for square and round objects. I need it with weird wavy shaped objects

Comment: It does polygons. Basically you need a script/tool which process a sprite to polygonial shape for the detection. Such tools such existm though might not be JS specific. Unfortunately I don't have any names to give out of my head :(