# Collision detection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to check collisions in jQuery in the animate feature. Heres my code,

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>nothing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 37) {
                $('.button0 input').animate({
                    'left': '+=' + Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px',
                    'top': '+=' + Math.sin(90 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px'
                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 39) {
                $('.button0 input').animate({
                    'left': '+=' + Math.cos(180 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px',
                    'top': '+=' + Math.sin(180 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px'
                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 38) {
                $('.button0 input').animate({
                    'left': '+=' + Math.cos(270 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px',
                    'top': '+=' + Math.sin(270 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px'
                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 40) {
                $('.button0 input').animate({
                    'left': '+=' + Math.cos(0 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px',
                    'top': '+=' + Math.sin(0 * Math.PI / 180) * 30 + 'px'
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .button0 input{
    position:fixed;
    left:142px;
    top:77px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:NORMAL;
    }
    .button1 input{
    position:fixed;
    left:333px;
    top:58px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:NORMAL;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="button0"><input type="button" style="width: 59px;height: 58px;" value="Button 0"/></div>
    <div class="button1"><input type="button" style="width: 113px;height: 76px;" value="Button 1"/></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

is there an event where we could check if button0 has collided with button1,

(without checking during the movement)

something like this would be nice (to have it as an event):

```
$('.button0 input').collision(function(".button1 input"){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not provide such functionality. You either have to write your own function for collision detection or use a 3d-party jQuery library. Have you tried [gameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/api.php#collision) library?

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection) worth a look. It has both jQuery and pure JavaScript solutions.