# How to make a Javascript collision?

Tags: javascript, collision

Programming is not forte, warning you.
I'm making a simple Javascript game. Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSwzW.png
Basically, I want to move the Hoff's head (he already follows my mouse) through the tomato-pickle corridor to reach the hamburger. However, when his head collides with the red ketchup barriers, you need to start again.
How in the world do I make this collision possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection)

Answer (score 2):

If the tomato line is flat then you can probably get away with something along the lines of:

```
 //hoff y position is above toplins y.
 //or hoffs y position+its hight is below the bottom lines y.
 if(hoff.y < topLine.y || (hoff.y+hoff.height) > bottomLine.Y) hoff.collided();
```

If you need to be more specific, I'd recommend just using a JavaScript framework to do it for you (you can do it yourself, but it involves a lot of math and TBH the works already been done so why reinvent the wheel).