# Check if two colours are touching using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, background, contacts

I am make a jquery game and I have a level as a background and instead of just having for each level lots of lines of code checking where it is, is there a way to check if two colors are touching. So the background and the character.

I would prefer to not use a plugin.

jquery for checking if it is touching one line:

```
if(level === 1) {
    if(c.css('left') === '90px') {
        c.css({'left': '115px', 'bottom': '94px'});
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/KPyxN/2/

Comment: "is there a way to check if two colors are touching" - no, not in the way it sounds like you want.

Comment: so is there a way to do what I want without the long way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We prefer questions to demonstrate a minimal amount of code, to better to reproduce the specific problem you're trying to solve. Read [the SO about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for more.

Comment: @Blazemonger just saying I am not new

Comment: will pos a fiddle and code for you

Comment: Then you should see right away that your question is unanswerable in its current form. Without more specifics, it's impossible to even guide you to more information.

Comment: sorry @Blazemonger have posted a fiddle

Comment: So you want to know if the blue box is over a specific color of your entire background image? I'm sorry, but JavaScript is unable to identify things like that. You need to rethink your entire approach. You might need to implement some kind of [collision detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
      var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/nGRwt/214/)**

Comment: will try with a different approach with that. thanks

Comment: didn't work as I planned have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/KPyxN/3/ should alert tough I know this is because I am using images. Is there a way around it?