# Circle Overlap Function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out how exactly this function might look like??
Help appreciated

Write a function circles_overlap that takes as input two circles as defined above. Your function must
check whether the circles overlap. If the circles overlap then your function shall return -1. If the circles
do not overlap then your function shall return 1. If the circles are touching then your function shall
return 0.

Comment: Post some code that what you have already tried.

Comment: I'm not quite sure on how to do it

Comment: check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection