# Dynamic element hit detection system not working

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

Within my project I have a character that automatically walks down the screen. I want to detect whenever the character hits a certain dungeon (each "dungeon" is a `div` with some text inside).

Here is my code in a simplified format:

```
//call the function
console.log(isCollide(characterData[0][0], document.getElementsByClassName("Dungeon_Wrapper_Room")[a])));

var isCollide = function(a, b) {
    //Used to parse get the x/y pixel coordinates by removing the "px" at the end of the string.
    var aTOPstr = a.style.top;
    var aTOP = (parseInt(aTOPstr.slice(0, aTOPstr.length-2)));
    var aLEFTstr = a.style.left;
    var aLEFT = (parseInt(aLEFTstr.slice(0, aLEFTstr.length-2)));

    var bTOPstr = b.style.top;
    var bTOP = (parseInt(bTOPstr.slice(0, bTOPstr.length-2)));
    var bLEFTstr = b.style.left;
    var bLEFT = (parseInt(bLEFTstr.slice(0, bLEFTstr.length-2)));
    console.log(((aTOP + 32) > (bTOP))+" "+(aTOP < (bTOP - 32))+" "+((aLEFT + 32) > bLEFT)+" "+(aLEFT < (bLEFT + 50)));

    return (
        !((aTOP + 32) < (bTOP)) ||
        (aTOP > (bTOP + 50)) ||
        ((aLEFT + 32) < aLEFT) ||
        (aLEFT > (aLEFT + 50))
    );

};
```

The character image was created dynamically (in the end I'll use a for loop to run through an array of characters, each with this detection).

```
var characterData = [
    [document.createElement("img"), {/*Misc. Character Data Goes Here*/}]
];
characterData[0][0].src = "images/characters/default.png";
characterData[0][0].style.position = "relative";
characterData[0][0].style.left += ((50-32)/2)+"px";
characterData[0][0].style.top += (-(50-32+25))+"px";
characterData[0][0].id = "character0";
tavernBox.appendChild(characterData[0][0]);
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="Town_Wrapper">
    <div id="townBoxWrapper">
        <div id="tavernBox">
            <!-- Characters are appended here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Dungeon_Wrapper">
    <div class='Dungeon_Wrapper_Room'>Boss
        <!--Box character is being detected with-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've based my hit detection off the answer I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7301852/7214959 but still am having no success.

I have absolutely no clue what is wrong with it. I've tried switching the `<` around and other functions but still can't find anything. I've also tried going from `relative` to `absolute` positioning and still got nothing. The isCollide function needs to return `true` or `!false` to indicate it has collided but each section of the if statement always returns "false" and there is never a single "true".

JSFiddle (contains debugging for console and alert): https://jsfiddle.net/drfyvLng/

Solved: The selected answer solves the issue presented in the jsfiddle. Within my own code I had to turn the certain dungeon into absolute positioning and find its location use `.offsetTOP` and `.offsetLEFT`. Additionally I made the return formula detect when the character is inside the box rather than when it isn't.

Comment: The expression in the `if`s condition is not the same as in the returned expression, `~ !== !`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few issues with the JSfiddle.

This was evaluating to null because there's no top set in the css style.

```
var bTOPstr = b.style.top;
```

Update your CSS to this and that part is covered.

```
<div class='Dungeon_Wrapper_Room' style="background-color: yellow; min-height:50px; top:0px; bottom:50px; left:0px; right:100px">
```

Then your if statement that checks collision is different to the one you based it off, be careful when copying code!

```
        !((aTOP + 32) < (bTOP)) ||
        (aTOP > (bTOP + 50)) ||
        ((aLEFT + 32) < aLEFT) ||
        (aLEFT > (aLEFT + 50))

aLeft + 32 < aLeft     should be     aLeft + 32 < bLeft
aLeft > aLeft + 50     should be     aLeft > bLeft + 50
```

Finally, you need another bracket on the if statement. The answer your based it off is checking '!' on the entire expression, yours just uses the first line.

So now it looks like this.

```
  !(((aTOP + 32) < (bTOP)) ||
    (aTOP > (bTOP + 50)) ||
    ((aLEFT + 32) < bLEFT) ||
    (aLEFT > (bLEFT + 50)))
```

Which should work.